# Only one APK with Camera2 and old camera API

Tags: android, camera2

I have an app that uses camera2 API and also the old camera version. The problem is that I need to generate a single APK with minSdkVersion 16 and camera2 does not compile together, for obvious reasons.

I gave a quick fix to the problem by making an exclusive photo app for Camera2. I detect the user's Android version and, if greater than or equal to 5.0 (21), trigger an Intent for this particular app. I could not get an elegant solution to this problem.

So... how can I generate only APK in this case?

Comment: You can try and learn from [opencamera](https://github.com/almalence/OpenCamera) to do what Commonsguy said

Comment: @rupinderjeet it's not good approach to me. Thanks for this suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option A: Using Both APIs

Step #1: Set your `compileSdkVersion` to 21 or higher. Ideally, set it to 25, for the latest version of Android.

Step #2: Write code for both APIs.

Step #3: Only call the code that uses the `android.hardware.camera2` classes when the device is running Android 5.0+:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  // use camera2
}
else {
  // use Camera
}
```

## Option B: Only Use the Classic Camera API

`android.hardware.Camera` works fine on Android 7.1 and older devices. Until such time as `android.hardware.Camera` is removed from the Android SDK, just use it. You will not be able to take advantage of any new features offered by the `android.hardware.camera2` classes, though.

Comment: Dear, my question is about how can i put camera2 in the same package (APK) using minSdk 16 to avoid another APK with the implementation of camera2 that requires minSdk as 21.
. compileSdkVersion is 25. I was implemented the Step #3 as you said.

Comment: @Mateus: "about how can i put camera2 in the same package (APK) using minSdk 16 to avoid another APK" -- that is Option A. My point with Option B is that what you are trying to do may not be worth the effort. "I was implemented the Step #3 as you said" -- then why did you ask the question, since you already implemented it?

Comment: @Mateus: For example, I have been using Option A in [this library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2) and its associated apps for over a year. I have tested it on 50+ devices, and the approach works fine.